# How to prevent someone from using my domain in Amazon SES -- they are sending emails from my domain with a different email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, security, cloud, amazon-ses

So I recived an email from AWS that someone is using my domain for spamming.

I checked the details of the email that was sent and I detected that if my domain is `myapp`,
and I am usually sending emails from email address `office@myapp.com`. I noticed that the hacker is using the mail `073office@myapp.com` which is very similar to my business email.

This address `073office@myapp.com` is not verified in my SES verified emails, but he is still using my ARN somehow.

How can I prevent it? Is there a way to configure SES only from one email?

Comment: Do you have control over your domain?

Comment: I do I have in in my Route53

Comment: This might be more on topic on another site within the stack exchange family of sites like https://security.stackexchange.com, but please take their tour to make sure before asking there.

Comment: How do you know that they are sending the email via Amazon SES? If you look at the message headers, it should show which system sent the email, with a unique ID from that system. Please add this information to your Question.

Answer (score 0):

are you able to see in SES logs if the emails are being sent from your SES? if yes, try creating new SES credentials and disable the existing ones, to avoid them using the current ones. If not, they are probably using external SMTP and spamming using your domain and this is something that you can't do much to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently one of our access keys was leaked and was included in the frontend's cache. I generated a new Access Key and disabled the old one , I also improved security configurations for the server.
I also configured SNS for bounces and complaint management and reconfigured my SES to use Hard Fail and improved DKIM , SPF and MAIL TO